# feel stupid, but, how code checkbox in form?

Tags: cartthrob, checkbox

I do not understand why the examples in the manual not work. Here in the forum I do not see the ricgt code as well. I feel stupid.

I have a field, defined as checkboxes, values populated by other field. (I do not know how many values my client fills in there)

Please, how do I code this in my form?
In the form, when coding {MYFIELDNAME} it just puts out all the values, no checkboxes there.
This code does not work either:

```
{options:MYFIELDNAME}
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="{MYFIELDNAME}" name="{MYFIELDNAME}[]" value="{option_value}"{checked}> {option_value}
</label>
{/options:MYFIELDNAME}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second time lucky!

I believe that Hansl was actually trying to have a check box field populate CartThrob item options.

That can be achieved by replacing his code with...

```
<select name="item_options[maat]">
  {maat}
    <option value="{item}">{item}</option>
  {/maat}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't feel stupid! You were very close.

The only thing you need to change is the `ID` and `name` attributes don't need the `{}`'s around them.

It should work if you make it...

```
{options:MYFIELDNAME}
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="MYFIELDNAME" name="MYFIELDNAME[]" value="{option_value}"{checked}> {option_value}
    </label>
{/options:MYFIELDNAME}
```

Comment: I am so sorry, that code did not output OK. I tried also with closing the input tag, no luck.

Comment: Input tags are self closing, so no need to close that with`</input>`. what is your field name actually called?

Comment: Complex commenting system, not used to, sorry. this i my tag with original field name {options:maat}
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="maat" name="maat[]" value="{option_value}"{checked}> {option_value} />
    </label>
{/options:maat}

Comment: That '/>' is definitely superfluous so should be removed. Could you email me login to the control panel to webdesign@andief.com and I will take a look into it for you and report back here with the answer for everyone else.

Comment: I do appreciate this VERY much. I have send you a mail to the address I found on your site.