# database problem checkboxes? Profile:edit form, checkbox error

Tags: channel-form, profile-edit, checkbox

Spending several hours to tackle this, completely exhausted and see no solution any more.
Do hope for some help here.
Code 1 no problem.
Code 2 throws error
Field niveau has three items. all throw error.

```
The form you submitted contained the following errors

Invalid Selection
Invalid Selection
Invalid Selection
```

In a form this code:

**Code 1**

```
<ul class="forms-inline-list">
                 {options:gender_{language_code}}
            <li>
        <input type="radio" id="gender_{language_code}" name="gender_{language_code}[]" value="{option_value}"{checked}>
        <label for="checkbox">{option_value}</label>
            </li>
                {/options:gender_{language_code}}
               </ul>
```

**code 2**

```
<ul class="forms-inline-list">
                 {options:niveau_{language_code}}
            <li>
        <input type="radio" id="niveau_{language_code}" name="niveau_{language_code}[]" value="{option_value}"{checked}>
        <label for="checkbox">{option_value}</label>
            </li>
                {/options:niveau_{language_code}}
               </ul>
```

I swear, the two fields are the same, except for the name.

What is going on here?

Thanks a lot for saving may days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to [feel stupid, but, how code checkbox in form?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/19877/feel-stupid-but-how-code-checkbox-in-form)

Chris Barret from [Mightybigrobot](https://mightybigrobot.com) (makers of Cartthrob abd Profile:edit) helped me out.
The brackets have to go in a checkbox or radio select field. 
Working code is

```
<ul class="forms-inline-list">
                 {options:gender}
            <li>
        <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="{option_value}"{checked}>
        <label for="checkbox">{option_value}</label>
            </li>
                {/options:gender}
               </ul>
```